# How to retroactively delete a commit from a git repository?

Tags: git

I want to remove a commit from a git repository. Not the last one, thus a `git reset` won't work.

I have this: `A->B->C->D->...`

And now I want to have only

```
A->B->D->...
```

Thus, I want to change the past on a way as if `C` never had been existed.

How can I do that?

The possible inconsistencies with the remote repositories are a non-issue (I have full control over them). It is not a problem if the commit ids change, too.

Comment: Do you want the changes of C to remain even though C isn't in history anymore?

Comment: @Shiva What I get by checking out `D`, should remain the same. Thus, the changes of `C` and `D` should remain, only `C` has to be made non-existing.

Comment: Unrelated, but isn't retroactively the *only* way you could delete a commit?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes :-) You are absolutely right. But the human language is highly redundant, and I think this a case as this redundancy actually improves the comprehensibility (it puts the focus to the retroactivity).

Comment: @peterh One thing to note is that if you're using a service like GitHub, there are public hooks to read public repos as soon as they are pushed to, so if you're trying to delete a commit that may contain sensitive data or keys (like AWS credentials), you should probably treat that committed data as if it's public at this point. (This has bit a member of my team in the past)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a simple, linear set of changes to copy to new commits, use `git rebase -i` as in [Alejandro C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418344/1256452).  If not, do not mix `git rebase -i` with `git rebase -p`: it really won't work well.

Instead, first, use `git replace` to construct an alternative history: make a replacement for the commit that comes after the one(s) you want removed, where the replacement's parent is the next-earlier commit you want Git to "see" when it uses replacements (which it does by default).  Then, once you have the desired history, run an otherwise-no-operation `git filter-branch` to copy the commits.  The copied commits will, like the rest of Git, use the "pretend history" from the replacement, so they will in fact have that as their *real* history, and when `git filter-branch` makes the branch names point to the newly copied branch tips, the replacement history will now *be* the actual history.

(Then, as with any `git filter-branch` operation, you must clean away the `refs/original/` references.  It's also wise to all of this in a temporary spare repository in case you goof it up. :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Use `git rebase -i B` then squash the commit that you don't want (but whose changes you want to keep; delete it if you don't want the changes) (where B is the ref of the parent of the commit you want to delete).

You'll get something like the following

```
pick B Good commit
squash C Commit message I don't want, but whose changes I do want
pick D Good commit 

# Rebase B..D onto B
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Comment: Wouldn't it unify my branches? I really won't do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by unify branches; merge? No, it won't merge your branches.

Comment: Not merge, but linearization. What was merged by whom and when, it is an important information in the commit history of the project, and I won't lose that info.

Comment: No, you won't lose anything other than the commit you delete.

Comment: Thanks, it seems working. It created a new anonymous branch, but I understand its reason (of course the HEAD and the branch references weren't overwritten). I wait a little bit, maybe also a rebase-free solution arrives. If doesn't, you get the pipe.

Comment: @peterh if you want to keep the changes from C, use squash, not delete.

Comment: this command will discard all merges that occur after B! you can tell rebase to try and preserve merges by passing the -p flag. I have read warnings about using -p and -i together, but on a simple example it worked, so it might be worth a shot here